# Python Telnetlib response problem for a read_all

Tags: python, telnet

to explain to you I reproduce a telnet client in python and so I start by logging in and entering the identifiers (password and username) then I test a command to see if it works (dir ) . The problem is that I want to display the details at the end with the read_all but as soon as I get to this point I have no answer then the freeze program I looked for many solutions on stackoverflow but none helped me

```
import telnetlib
import sys
import socket
import time

tel = telnetlib.Telnet("localhost",  23, timeout = 1)
tel.open("localhost" , 23)

tel.read_until(b"Username:")
tel.write(("Username").encode('ascii') + b"\n")

tel.read_until(b"Password:")
tel.write(("Password").encode('ascii') + b"\n")

time.sleep(5)

tel.read_until(b">")
tel.write(("dir").encode('ascii') + b"\n")

print(tel.read_all().decode('ascii'))

tel.close()
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: For "proper" telnet, the line-ending is `\r\n`.